# Finding sequence for 0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Do we know a formula for the following sequence?

$$0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7...$$

I have already tried finding a sequence formula for the sequence above, but I couldn't find any mathematical formula to describe it. I also have already tried finding the sequence using online software but also failed. Can someone help me please, thank you guys.!

Comment: $\lfloor (n+2)/3\rfloor$ ?

Comment: this cannot be expressed in other ways not using the floor function? @Exodd

Comment: it doesn't give the 0 term for n=1

Comment: Exodd's formula starts indexing from $n = 0$.  You need to shift it accordingly if you start indexing from $n = 1$.

Comment: I think that if you play around you can get what you want as a sum of three similar terms, the first being $\frac{n}{3}(\frac{1^n+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}}{3})$. Here $\omega\ne 1$ is a cube root of $1$. Finding the other two is left as an exercise.

Comment: For several other formulas, see [OEIS sequence A002264](https://oeis.org/A002264) and shift appropriately.

Comment: If you want to see where @ancientmathematician 's solution is coming from, study the [linear difference equations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) and notice that the sequence satisfies the recurrence $a_{n+3}-a_n=1$ with first three terms equal to $0,1,1$ respectively. Then solve that recurrence. The solution will involve the solutions of the polynomial equation $x^3-1=0$, which happen to be $1, \omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

As Exodd points out in the comments above, a transformation of the floor function will do the trick.

If you'd prefer not to use the floor function, then one can give it as a piecewise function, such as $$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{3} & n\equiv0\pmod3,\\\frac{n-1}{3} & n\equiv 1\pmod 3,\\\frac{n+1}{3} & n\equiv 2\pmod 3.\end{cases}$$